Actual Prayaschitta for non-virgin people [Serious]
I have gone through all types of Dharma-sastras, having mixed views and re-marriage and marriage of women. But, I have consistently seen that for the first marriage, only kanyas are considered. There is no other meaning for a kanya at all other than a virgin.
Now, I have unfortunately found out that my daughter has engaged in pre-maritial intercourse. She regrets it now as well. But according to orthodox brahmin rituals, she cannot be wedded. That's it.
But she wants to do prayaschitta for this. I am honestly asking and praying, is there any prayaschitta for this? This post is no joke, hence please suggest any measures if they exist.
I have asked others, and they have said no such prayaschitta is needed. But the sastras verdict is final hence I am seeking guidance with honest motives. Please help.

As per the Shiva Purana, repentance (Paschatapa) is the only way to be freed from all kinds of sins and be purified along with hearing the glories of Shiva, even without a separate Prayaschitta.


Repentance is the only way of acquittance for all sinners. Saintly men
have extolled it as the only way of expiation for all sins.



After due Prayaschitta, he or she becomes free from fear. By repentance, he or she attains salvation undoubtedly.



The mental purity that one derives on hearing the story of Śivapurāṇa
cannot be gained by any other means.

Source: Cañculā's salvation from the Śivapurāṇa-māhātmya
Similar statements can also be found in other scriptures.

The devotees are naturally faultless. Accidental sins committed by a
devotee are sincerely regretted, and by the grace of the Lord all sins
unwillingly committed by a devotee are burnt in the fire of
repentance (Shrimad Bhagavatam 1.19.1 Purport).
Repentance comes in the mind of a good soul as soon as he commits
something wrong (Shrimad Bhagavatam 1.18.31 Purport)


Hello, thank you for you answer. But this act of my daughter is an act of permanent ritualistic impurity. The above quoted passage does not show how she can become fit for marriage. This is similar to how people devoted to Harinama are considered equal/maybe even above than brahmanas, but never entitled to the rituals of the brahmanas.
Similarly, this example does not entitle/make fit such a woman for a ritual as sacred as marriage.
I humbly request you, is there any real prayaschitta for this?

Sorry ji, couldn't find exactly what you were requesting. Through prayaschitta, one may become free from a specific sin and become eligible once again to participate in rituals but unfortunately one cannot be freed from the sinful propensity which makes the soul suffer endlessly. So one will ultimately have to take shelter of the actual prayaschitta recommended by Sri Suta above.

Prayashchitta may remove the sin attached but does not make the girl maiden again for marriage. Unfortunately, as said in above comment, probably wont find a specific answer for this. HOWEVER, these days we do see lot of marriages of divorced women. But...Any second 'marriage' examples I am aware are where the girl becomes maiden again (through some sort of boons). If you have a trusted (who would keep discussions private) brahmana priest, may be ask their guidance and proceed based on that.

In popular terms what is called "pre-marital intercourse" will be considered Gandharva marriage.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriage_in_Hinduism  (Gandharva vivah)
As a father you can't get her married, that is already clear to you.
It's a lost chance. Situation may not qualify for prayashchita.
Now she may pursue life with higher purposes ranging from - sadhana to social service.

this is an opinion based comment and not answer. Please review the guidelines for answering.

Updated my answer.

Wiki is not valid source. Also, Gandarva vivah doesn't allow intercourse before marriage. Even there, there is formality of marriage.

Kanthri ji, 1) your own comment comes without any reference. 2) You are supposed to follow the references within Wikipedia article. As I observe, Gandharva vivah section of article is well referenced.
